# Add filter on html tags,attributes on specific function in wordpress

Tags: plugins, customization, theme-development

Title is little bit :S
sorry :)
For example,we have paginate links function that output html something like this

```
<span class='page-numbers current'>some number</span>
```

How can I filter that,to remove that span,class,to apply my own html tags,styles,tnx in advance.I just want to apply my own styles and html tags,is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom pagination function:

my source:

```
function fb_paging_bar( $args = array() ) {

    $defaults = array(
        'range'           => 4,
        'custom_query'    => FALSE,
        'previous_string' => __( '&laquo;&laquo;&laquo;', FB_GREYFOTO_TEXTDOMAIN ),
        'next_string'     => __( '&raquo;&raquo;&raquo;', FB_GREYFOTO_TEXTDOMAIN ),
        'view_fp'         => TRUE,
        'view_lp'         => TRUE,
        'before_output'   => '<div class="postlink">',
        'after_output'    => '</div>'
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args( 
        $args, 
        apply_filters( 'fb_paging_bar_defaults', $defaults )
    );

    $args['range'] = (int) $args['range'] - 1;
    if ( !$args['custom_query'] )
        $args['custom_query'] = @$GLOBALS['wp_query'];
    $count = (int) $args['custom_query']->max_num_pages;
    $page  = intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
    $ceil  = ceil( $args['range'] / 2 );

    if ( $count <= 1 )
        return FALSE;

    if ( !$page )
        $page = 1;

    if ( $count > $args['range'] ) {
        if ( $page <= $args['range'] ) {
            $min = 1;
            $max = $args['range'] + 1;
        } elseif ( $page >= ($count - $ceil) ) {
            $min = $count - $args['range'];
            $max = $count;
        } elseif ( $page >= $args['range'] && $page < ($count - $ceil) ) {
            $min = $page - $ceil;
            $max = $page + $ceil;
        }
    } else {
        $min = 1;
        $max = $count;
    }

    $echo = '';
    $previous = intval($page) - 1;
    $previous = esc_attr( get_pagenum_link($previous) );
    if ( $previous && (1 != $page) )
        $echo .= '<a href="' . $previous . '" title="' . __( 'previous', FB_GREYFOTO_TEXTDOMAIN) . '">' . $args['previous_string'] . '</a>';
    $firstpage = esc_attr( get_pagenum_link(1) );

    if ( $args['view_fp'] && $firstpage && (1 != $page) )
        $echo .= '<a href="' . $firstpage . '">' . __( 'First', FB_GREYFOTO_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '</a>';

    if ( !empty($min) && !empty($max) ) {
        for( $i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++ ) {
            if ($page == $i) {
                $echo .= '<span class="active">' . str_pad( (int)$i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT ) . '</span>';
            } else {
                $echo .= sprintf( '<a href="%s">%002d</a>', esc_attr( get_pagenum_link($i) ), $i );
            }
        }
    }

    if ($args['view_lp']) {
        $lastpage = esc_attr( get_pagenum_link($count) );
        if ( $lastpage && ($count != $page) ) {
            $count = str_pad( (int)$count, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
            $echo .= '<a href="' . $lastpage . '">' . __( 'Last', FB_GREYFOTO_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '(' . $count . ')' . '</a>';
        }
    }

    $next = intval($page) + 1;
    $next = esc_attr( get_pagenum_link($next) );
    if ($next && ($count != $page) )
        $echo .= '<a href="' . $next . '" title="' . __( 'next', FB_GREYFOTO_TEXTDOMAIN) . '">' . $args['next_string'] . '</a>';

    if ( isset($echo) )
        echo $args['before_output'] . $echo . $args['after_output'];
}
```

also you can hook inside the function for custom format and variables.

also an example:

```
function change_fb_paging_bar_defaults($args) {

    $args['previous_string'] = ''; // empty string
    $args['next_string'] = '';

    return $args;
}
add_filter('fb_paging_bar_defaults', 'change_fb_paging_bar_defaults');
```

in your template sonly use the function:

```
fb_paging_bar();
```

Comment: Tnx,this looks great.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do it would be to copy that function (wp-includes/general-template.php, line 1943) and create your own with the markup you want.

Comment: I did that,but I'm not happy with that :( maybe some regex can fix issue? paginate links is just example function,there are many,many more function that we sometimes need to change default markup.Tnx for response

Comment: You can use the argument `'type' => 'array'` to return the pagination links as an array and use a replace function on each element to change the markup. But I would not recommend that for this function because I think it is too much processing. If you have other functions, you should deal with them on a case by case basis and use str_replace, or preg_replace, or copy the function, or use a filter included in the function. You should find the best solution performance-wise for each function, not a one-size fit-all solution. And I think a copy is the best for this, not a regex or other replace.

Comment: small hint: WPEngineer.com publish in the next view days an custom pagination function to use in theme

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible ways to customize markup, it depends on specific function:

- lookup function on deeper level that is used to retrieve data, use it with own markup;
- check if output is passed through filter, use filter to make replacements;
- markup is generated with walker class, create own walker and pass it to function.

There are probably more ways, but I think these are common.

Overall I think WP markup is reasonably usable and semantic. Most cases I had too mess with it are JS stuff requiring very specific markup.

Did you consider it may be more consistent and viable to make CSS fit generic markup?